# Can no persist entity with lazy loading elements

Tags: jpa

I have entities

```
@Entity public class A implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<B> bList;
}

@Entity public class B implements Serializable{
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private A a;

    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private C c;
}

@Entity public class C implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "c", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private B b;
}
```

if I  pass B entity to ejb method from remote client, then entity
passed to app server is NULL; If I change LAZY loading to EAGER, then every thing goes well.
I do not want to use EAGER loading, how to avoid EAGER loading?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can persist instance of B type, received from remote client is restore state of its children from old copy and then persist.

```
public B updateFromRemote(B b) {
   B oldCopy = bDao.findBById(b.getId());
   b.setA(oldCopy.getA());
   b.setC(oldCopy.getC());
   return bDao.save(b);
}
```

Comment: from remote client I pass new instance of B. B newb=new B();  newb.set(new C(...)); newb.set(oldA);  and after pass newB to server.

Comment: To make it clear, when you initialize instance of B remotely and then pass it to server, the b.getC() equals null?

Comment: yes.  after initializing of B on client side and passing it to server side, B  instance passed to server is NULL. JPA provaider is eclipselink and app server gf 3.

Comment: Sounds like you have to check object serialization graph and find place where your remotely initialized instance of class B gets turned to NULL. I'd like to help further but I'm not familiar with neither EcliplseLink nor GF3.

Comment: thanks !  how to check object serialization?  I create test case and check entity data before passing to remote ejb method and after that check Entity instance on server, but passed Entity is null. how to monitor object serialization process?